# vga error after automatic update in 16.04

Tags: 16.04, updates, intel-graphics, vga, screen-corruption

16.04 LTS: after an automatic update, the images in the screen get distorced in web browsers:
[image]

Problem remains unfixed still today!

Comment: I follow the sugestion in this post: http://askubuntu.com/questions/851561/problems-with-display/851688#851688 and i run:
apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
apt-get install --reinstall nautilus
and it get much better but not tottaly fixed.

Comment: there was another update few days ago but the problem with the video remains.

Comment: i installed a new computer with a fresh instalation of the Ubuntu and the problem remains!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this url: https://01.org/linuxgraphics It contains a automatic tool to install and keep update the Intel vga drivers in Ubuntu 16.10. It does not work for previous versions of Ubuntu.