# Problems with display

Tags: intel-graphics, 16.10, screen-corruption

I've been a Linux user for many years, but I've never taken a close look into the display/windowing system, with which I seem to have an issue at the moment.

Let me describe the various issues that I think might be connected, as they seem to be correlated:

- the display seems to 'crash' sometimes, about once or twice a day.

  [image]

  [Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/hyqp4ohikcqkx30/2016-11-17%2017.11.53.mp4?dl=0) is a video. What's interesting, is that only the background image seems affected, not the launcher or icons on the desktop. A hardware problem seems unlikely therefore.
- When I click an item on the menu bar (let's say, 'File' in Firefox, and the File menu expands), and then move and hover over to the next item ('Edit'), the Edit menu does not expand, until I click on it. A reboot of the system fixes it (so that not-clicked menu items expand on hover). I'm not exactly sure what triggers it, but it seems to be the occurrence of the display issue above.
- When I copy a file with nautilus, a progress bar is shown. Dolphin, however, does not show anything. I'm used to seeing a progress dialog. A KDE-on-Unity issue maybe? Not sure if it is related to the other 2 issues in the list, but I thought I'd add it for completeness just in case.

My system is a dell xps 13 i7 (kabylake) running Ubuntu Linux 16.10.

Diagnostics:

- [`/var/log/Xorg.0.log`](https://paste.ubuntu.com/23513549/)

Let me know if any more information is necessary for diagnostic purposes, and many thanks in advance.

Comment: edited the question to include the output

Comment: Considering that Dell offers the options to ship the XPS 13 with Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, could you please try whether you have the same issues with a 16.04 live system?

Comment: (corrected an error in the link)

Comment: @DavidFoerster: yes there are multiple issues, but as they all concern the display, and seem to occur simultaneously, I'm assuming they have the same underlying cause. I could be mistaken of course. I think I actually solved the projector-related issues today, so I'll remove those. Which remaining issues do you think are unrelated?

Comment: I clearified the relationship between the issues

Comment: I have the same problem and i reported here:  http://askubuntu.com/questions/846806/vga-error-after-automatic-update-in-16-04

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem comes from nautilus or from ubuntu-desktop. I also have this problem sometimes (something like 1 time a week) and I resolve it by pressing Super+S (it shows all the workspaces).

You can try to resolve reinstall nautilus and ubuntu-desktop (pay attention that Ubuntu reinstall all the packages removed when you reinstall these packages) or just by keeping Ubuntu up to date (I think that this bug affect multiple users and should be corrected soon)

Comment: have you found this bug in launchpad? I've never seen anything like that picture!

Comment: no, I didn't search for